# Can a Facebook application impersonate a Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've just spent all day going through broken examples, outdated code, poor documentation and frustration, so bear with me. I need to do a sanity check here. I have this:

- A personal Facebook account, as in me
- A Facebook fan page created under above account, called "JungleDragon"
- A Facebook application called "JungleDragon"

What I want is to automatically post updates to the wall of the fan page. The updates should not be posted by me, rather by the page itself.

I have gotten this to work (for a bit):

[image]

The second entry is a manual entry. The first one is automated via this code in PHP making use of the Facebook PHP SDK:

```
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook("", "");
$facebook->setAccessToken("");

try{
$facebook->api('/132114073492501/feed', 'POST', array('message' => 'test message'));
}catch(Exception $o ){
print_r($o);
}
```

I have left the keys out of the example. The thing that bugs me is that the automated post is created "via JungleDragon", which is the app, not the page itself. This app has no use for end-users so my question is "**how to really post to the wall as the page, not the app?**"

Please don't send me to some general graph api page. I've been there and they suck.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Check out the `manage_page` permission.

Comment: The one who downvoted this, obviously didn't care for any explanation. I am pretty sure one could do this when I posted this, not sure whether its still possible or not.